# return value to df after several operations

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I run IPR outlier control for a relatively big dataframe df:
I perform IPR within subset of the data so I use for loop.

How can I return value to original df >1 000 000 rows:

```
        months product  brick  units  is_outlier
0       202104  abc      3   1.00       False
1       202104  abc      6   3.00       False
```

```
for product in df['product'].unique():
    for brick in df['brick'].unique():
        try:
                # Extract the units for the current product and brick
                data = df.loc[(df['product'] == product) & (df['brick'] == brick)]['units'].values

                # Scale the data
                scaler = StandardScaler()
                data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape(-1, 1))

                # Fit a linear regression model to the data
                reg = LinearRegression()
                reg.fit(np.arange(len(data_scaled)).reshape(-1, 1), data_scaled)

                # Calculate the residuals of the regression
                residuals = data_scaled - reg.predict(np.arange(len(data_scaled)).reshape(-1, 1))

                # Identify any observations with a residual larger than 2 standard deviations from the mean
                threshold = 2*residuals.std()
                outliers = np.where(np.abs(residuals) > threshold)

                # Set the "is_outlier" column to True for the outliers in the current product
                df.loc[(df['product'] == product ) & (df['brick']== brick) & (df.index.isin(outliers[0])), 'is_outlier'] = True
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: `for brick in df['brick'].unique():` sounds like a job for `groupby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @QuangHoang suggested, use `groupby` and `apply` your custom function:

```
def outlier(df):
    data = df.to_numpy().reshape((-1, 1))

    # Scale the data
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    data_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(data)

    # Fit a linear regression model to the data
    reg = LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(np.arange(len(data_scaled)).reshape(-1, 1), data_scaled)

    # Calculate the residuals of the regression
    residuals = data_scaled - reg.predict(np.arange(len(data_scaled)).reshape(-1, 1))

    # Identify any observations with a residual
    # larger than 2 standard deviations from the mean
    threshold = 2*residuals.std()

    return np.ravel(np.abs(residuals) > threshold)


df['is_outlier'] = df.groupby(['product', 'brick'])['units'].transform(outlier)
```